# oauth token does not contain information about roles or scope

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have created app registration in AD, created client secret and exposed the API. I have created App Role and added permissions (additional permissions to the default graph user read). I also have added a scope.

When I do the request

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=<application id>' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=<secret>' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=api://<application id>/.default' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

I get the response containing *access_token*. However when I decode the token it does not contain any roles, scopes or anything

```
{
"aud": "api://<application id>",
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>/",
"iat": 1672241639,
"nbf": 1672241639,
"exp": 1672245539,
"aio": "<>",
"appid": "<application id>",
"appidacr": "1",
"idp": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>/",
"oid": "<>",
"rh": "<>.",
"sub": "<>",
"tid": "<tenant id>",
"uti": "<>",
"ver": "1.0"
}
```

What is missing?

`/oauth2/token` returns similar response

```
{
    "aud": "<resource id>",
    "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>/",
    "iat": 1672241960,
    "nbf": 1672241960,
    "exp": 1672245860,
    "aio": "<>",
    "appid": "<application id>",
    "appidacr": "1",
    "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/<tenant id>/",
    "oid": "<>",
    "rh": "<>",
    "sub": "<>",
    "tenant_region_scope": "EU",
    "tid": "<tenant id>",
    "uti": "<>",
    "ver": "1.0",
    "xms_tdbr": "EU"
}
```

Comment: Could you try generating token with **v2 endpoint**: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token`

Comment: pretty similar responses but different `aud` value and `v2.0` returns less fields. still no scopes or roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via Postman and got below results:***

I registered one Azure AD application and created **App role** named `READER.ALL` like below:

[image]

Now I exposed one API named `ReaderScope.ALL` same as you like below:

[image]

Now I generated the token using **Client credentials** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: <appID>
client_secret: <secret>
scope: api://<appID>/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I decoded the token, I did not find **`roles`** claim same as you like below:

[image]

To get **`roles`** claim in the token, you need to add **API permission** like below:

[image]

Now, select Application permissions and add the **App role** like below:

[image]

Make sure to grant **admin consent** to the added permission like below:

[image]

When I generated the token again now and decoded it, I got **`roles`** claim successfully like below:

[image]

You will get only **Application** permissions in **`roles`** claim while using client credentials flow.

To get **Delegated** permissions in  **`scp`** claim, you need to use interactive flows like authorization code flow etc.

Comment: I see. So it was due admin consent. As I am not allowed to grant admin consent, I guess to get the roles I will have to request via our internal system. Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same setup, but I still don't get roles. I know I have the roles assigned, because I restricted the application I am trying to grant permission to only assigned users.

Comment: Could you post new question with what flow you tried and where you stuck?